# react-native-firebase: Show firebase notifications depending on user settings

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

In our app user receives all kind of notifications.
And we also have Notifications permission screen where we can toggle permission for specific notification types "news", "friend request" and so on.

For foreground notifications we can check notification data for specific field and then display or not display Notification depending on current settings.

How can we do it for background notifications? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

[FCM steps React native](https://www.djamware.com/post/5d7773f05d8cdc057b603e65/react-native-firebase-cloud-messaging-fcm-push-notification)

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/customizedimgaepickerproject/notification

Setting.gradle

```
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, 
'../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
```

react-native link react-native-firebase

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>


build.gradle --app 
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1"
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'

compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
    transitive = false
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  //in bottom build.gradle app level


 MainAppliaction 


 import io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingPackage;
 import io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage;

       packages.add(new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage());
       packages.add(new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage());
```